# Why does $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} {\frac{1+\cos(x)}{1}}$ have no limit?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, trigonometry

I've tried to solve this question for a while but as of yet I can't seem to make sense of this. Why does $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} {\frac{1+\cos(x)}{1}}$ have no limit? Shouldn't it be $\infty$?

Comment: How could it be $\infty$? $-1\leq \cos x\leq 1$, so $\frac{1+\cos x}{1} = 1+\cos x \leq 2$ for all $x$.

Comment: Why do you write $1+\cos x$ as $\frac{1+\cos x}{1}$?

Comment: @uniquesolution My guess is someone applied L'Hopital's rule to something of the form $\frac{f(x)}{x}$, and didn't simplify a division by $1$.

Comment: The original equation was $\frac{x+\sin x}{x}$ and the question stated that you have to prove that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} {\frac{f'()x}{g'(x)}}$ diverges, $f(x)=x+ \sin(x)$, $g(x)=x$.

Comment: Intuitively:  A limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x) = L$ means that $f(x)$ gets closer and closer to $L$ as $x$ gets large.  Here it doesn't happen, because $1 + \cos(x)$ just oscillates forever without ever approaching any particular number.

Comment: @JairTaylor That makes so much sense. Thanks. Now how would you mathematically prove that?

Comment: @SkiMask gimusi's answer is basically doing this. along the sequence $x_n$, it takes all the crests of the oscillating wave, whereas on the sequence $y_n$, it takes all the zeros. You could also define a sequence $z_n=\pi+2\pi n$ along which it takes values on the troughs of the wave. This shows that no unique limit exists.

Comment: @SkiMask Do you know the precise definition of limit using $\epsilon$'s? You need to write it out carefully, negate it, and prove the negation.  Or you could use some theorems, if you have any.

Comment: As a general rule which works for both discrete $n$ and continuous $x$, no matter which value $n$ or $x$ tends to (a number or $\infty$), no matter what limit value is (a number or $\infty$), calculate $\liminf$ and $\limsup$, which are *always* defined.  If $\liminf < \limsup$, then limit doesn't exist.

Comment: @GNUSupporter: very true, but these concepts of $\limsup, \liminf $ are more difficult to understand than the concept of a limit. For such simple problems the definition of limit is not that difficult to apply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let consider

$$x_n=2\pi n \quad x_n\to+\infty \quad n\to +\infty$$

$$y_n=\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n \quad y_n\to+\infty \quad n\to +\infty$$

then

$${\frac{1+\cos(x_n)}{1}}\to2\neq{\frac{1+\cos(y_n)}{1}}\to1$$

thus

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} {\frac{1+\cos(x)}{1}}$$

does not exists.

Answer (score 1):

For some limit as $x\to x_0$ to be equal to $\infty$, this means that we can make the function arbitrarily large as we get closer to $x_0$. In this example, the function ($1+\cos x$) never gets larger than $2$. So the limit cannot be $\infty$.

By considering two different sequences, one where $\cos x=1$, and one where $\cos x=-1$, you can show that along two different paths as $x\to\infty$, we get two different limits. So this means that no limit exists.

Answer (score 0):

$$1+\cos x = 2 \cos^2 \left(\frac{x}{2}\right).$$

$\cos x$ oscillates between $1$ and $0$ in the first quadrant even as $n \to \infty$. Hence $\cos \frac{x}{2}$ also oscillates. I.e. it does not tend to a definite limiting value.

Comment: Just inserted a line for improving readability